# Problems with 14.04 most recent updates and possibly kernel

Tags: 14.04, unity, kernel, compiz, desktop-environments

I am still fairly new to Linux and Ubuntu, so I will apologize ahead of time for my ignorance. I am using working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have been using Ubuntu for a little over a year now, I am still learning coding and commands, and learning the Ubuntu desktop. My issue is this:

Ubuntu has been working fine until the recent updates I allowed it to update to. I so far have not been able to figure out what is happening.

After the most recent updates I lose all functionality of the desktop, the sidebar has empty white icons and title bar has no functionality for the power icon, wifi icon and Bluetooth icon, if they even show at all. Sometimes the desktop image will show, and sometimes it won't.

On my original install of 14.04 LTS I had a similar issue, which I eventually found was a improper video driver. After repairing, my issue was resolved. However, since the updates this repair is not working. I was thinking it might be an issue with unity, Ubuntu-desktop, or compiz, but have removed and reinstalled all, along with my NVidia driver and no improvement. I also am starting to believe it may be an issue with the most recent kernel update.

If any one has ideas or know of any recent kernel issues, I am open to anything. Just what ever you suggest please be descriptive as possible, as I stated I am still learning Linux and Ubuntu.

Any help would be great, at this point I am lost.

Comment: First tell me what graphics card do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention my system, it is a Toshiba Techra M7 with an internal Nvidia quadro nvs 110M 128 MB video card. The driver package I am using is the nvidia-304.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest kernel then.To do that you need to install the linux-generic-lts-vivid package.To do so type this in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: Will this just install the latest kernel? If this causes issues can I just remove the same package?

Comment: It will just install the latest kernel so if it causes any issues you can just remove it by using the apt-get remove command.

Comment: Make sure to use Nvidia-352 driver for the 3.19 Kernel.

Comment: I tried installing the package but it cant find it. Is there a ppa I need to add?

Comment: Already did, no help.

Comment: Did you install Synaptic?

Comment: No, just pretty much a basic Ubuntu install with a couple of small programs I use.

Comment: Then install Synaptic and search for the package linux-generic-lts-vivid in it.

Comment: ok, installed symantic. got the linux kernel update done also.

Comment: So is your problem fixed?

Comment: not sure, need to reboot, but also need to check the video drivers...

Comment: Dhartman3076,Reread my Second answer.I detailed the instructions on how to install it there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm adding another answer seeing as the comments won't allow spaces :>)

The linux-kernel-lts-vivid should show up in your repositories.If you can then maybe install Synaptic and in it search for the package using the Search bar.

To install Synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

To install the latest nvidia propeitary drivers.You need to add the PPA for it.To do so type this into the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia
```

After that to install it do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Comment: Dhartman3076,Are you still here?

Comment: Yes, installed synaptic and the linux kernel update. Does the new kernel not except the nvidia-304?

Comment: So you installed the 352 driver yet?

Comment: synaptic is not showing nvidia-352

Comment: Make sure that that you done my previous commands.If you done it then click the reload button in Synaptic and search for it again.If I'm assuming correct it should appear.

Comment: I have done the sudo apt-get update command, and reloaded synaptic, no help. it is not showing the nvidia-352

Comment: First did you add the ppa for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26523/discussion-between-dhartman3076-and-the-intelligent-human).

Comment: What is the ppa for it, I have not added it yet. Didn't know I needed to.

Comment: Dhartman I posted it in the chat room.Go there and you should be able to find the link.